# Free Wathcer and Alerting for Elastic Stack

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

As I read the artifcle, watch and alerting is paid version for gold member. Is there any standalone watcher and alerting to be integrated with Elastic Stack to monitor and alert if hit certain threshold in Kibana and Elasticsearch?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries or other off-site resources are off-topic according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines. See the section with the numbered list.

Answer (score 2):

go-elasticalert：
https://github.com/morningconsult/go-elasticsearch-alerts
elastcAlert：
https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert
sentinl：
https://github.com/sentinl/sentinl

Answer (score 2):

In contrary to Watcher which is a commercial feature, Alerting has some free components, it's not all commercial.

Whenever an alert is triggered you can store it in an index or log it into a file, that you can then read and act upon.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is also elastalert2: https://github.com/jertel/elastalert2
I've had good experience with it.  elastalert2 is a continuation of the Yelp version mentioned here previously by @caster.  It seems to be more currently maintained than the others.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35480678)